# 3-day old programming noob. List indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python

new to the place, and 3 days into learning programming. I am currently running through Code Academy (Python), and during one of my free-rein assignments I decided to write some code that wasn't relevant to the assignment just to test out some things I had learned.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
guns = ["AWP", "SSG 08", "SG 553", "SCAR-20 ", "G3SG1", "AK-47"]
print guns
print "Of the above mentioned Rifles, which one is the most accurate in CS:GO?", 
answer = raw_input()
answer_capitalize = answer.upper() 
correct_answer = guns[0]
if answer_capitalize == correct_answer:
    print "You are correct. The AWP is the most accurate weapon in CS:GO"

elif answer_capitalize == guns[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    print "I'm sorry. " + answer_capitalize + " is not correct. Please try again."

else:
    print "You spelled your weapon choice incorrectly. Please try again."
```

Here is the ERROR I am getting:  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 11, in 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

#### Line 11 being the elif statement (spacing is different on here)

There is no error code when inputting 'awp', but for any other input the error code is generated.

The objective of this little bit of kindergarden-grade code is to ask the question, which weapon is the most accurate. If they reply with awp, they get it right, if they choose the wrong weapon and spell it correctly, then the elif statement comes into play. If they butcher the weapon's spelling, or type anything other than a word on the list, then the else statement comes into play. Another nuisance was that it was printing both the IF and ELIF statements after input was received.

My next step, which I haven't even gotten to is looping back in the event they guess wrong. I am just trying to get the first half correct for the time being.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is on this line:

```
elif answer_capitalize == guns[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
```

You can't reference list items like this.

Instead, you could use

```
elif answer_capitalize in guns: #First if catches the correct answer
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Jozzas! Everything works as intended now :-D -- now on to looping for incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0):

Lists don't work that way.

```
elif answer_capitalize == guns[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
```

This is syntax error. **To get a sublist of a list**, you use `guns[1:5]`. However, in your case just get straight to the point and make it use `answer_capitalize != correct_answer`. To be even more specific and account for the "spelling errors", use `answer_capitalize in guns`.

In a case where the `guns` contained also lowercase items and you wanted to check if it's in the list case insensitively, you could transform `guns` to uppercase using list comprehensions: `guns_uppercase = [gun.upper() for gun in guns]`.

Comment: Umm, no, `guns[1..5]` is not how you get a sublist of a list. It's `guns[1:5]`. Maybe your colon fell over :).

Comment: Thanks all for the input, and everything said so far makes sense. Anyone want to provide a clue to me as to how I would start a loop for incorrect answers so they have another chance at guessing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar to what you have used in `if` statement.

```
elif answer_capitalize != correct_answer:
    print "I'm sorry. " + answer_capitalize + " is not correct. Please try again."
```

`!=` means not equal.

Answer (score 0):

As already spelt out, there's no concise syntax to get a non-contiguous sublist. You can however use a list comprehension:

```
elif answer_capitalize in [guns[i] for i in [1,2,3,4,5]]:
```

However probably it would be more efficient to do something like:

```
elif any(answer_capitalize==guns[i] for i in [1,2,3,4,5]):
```

Answer (score -1):

elif answer_capitalize == [0 for guns in range(5)]:

Comment: jozzas Answer is more accurate and efficent than mine.